# populating a DataTable with a JSON file directly, or querying a local spreadsheet (google visualization)

Tags: json, google-visualization

I am looking for the easiest way to populate a data table in google visualizations using either a json file or a local spreadsheet(.xlsx).

heres my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable.fromJSON(sampleData.json,0.6);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Heres my json file:

```
    {
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ] 
    }
```

When I run my code in my browser, I get 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: sampleData is not defined"

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You COULD simply place the contents of your JSON file right inline there in your HTML where the string "sampleData.JSON" is. That is, take out "sampleData.JSON" and replace it with the entire contents of your JSON file. I'm pretty sure you'll make some progress if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting sampleData.json in quotes, assuming that the filename is sampleData.json and is in the same folder as your HTML.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable.fromJSON('sampleData.json',0.6);
```